# Combine Two Rows in SQL? (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a wide table from a complex relational database. I've created a SQL query that generates a table like this:

| INCIDENT_ID | INCIDENT_DATE | INCIDENT_POSTCODE | PARTY_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20/07/18 | NG2 6HF | 1 |
| 1 | 20/07/18 | NG2 6HF | 2 |

....

Where for every incident_id incident_date & incident_postcode are identical, but because of the fact that multiple parties can be in an incident (up to 4) I have this problem of up to 4 rows per incident_id. Is it possible to combine these rows into 1 row? Something like this:

| INCIDENT_ID | INCIDENT_DATE | INCIDENT_POSTCODE | PARTY_ID | PARTY_ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20/07/18 | NG2 6HF | 1 | 2 |

My SQL query to create the original table is (more complex in real life but this is minimum reproducible code):

```
select I.INCIDENT_ID,
       I.INCIDENT_DATE,
       I.INCIDENT_POSTCODE,
       PA.PARTY_ID
from INCIDENT I
inner join PARTY PA
on PA.INCIDENT_ID = I.INCIDENT_ID
```

Comment: It might help to show data other than spaces.  I don't see what you really want here.

Comment: if the IDs match but field1 or field1 don't, what will happen then?

Comment: first provide with sample data

Comment: @tinazmu that won't happen as those fields are pulled from the incident table itself so will always be the same if the incident_id is the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I've added sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach: aggregate all the party ids into an array and then put each array element into a column. This works if the maximum number of party ids is a known value e.g. 4

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE ntest 
(
INCIDENT_id int,
incident_date date, 
incident_postcode varchar,
party_id int
)

INSERT INTO ntest 
VALUES 
    (1, '2018-07-20', 'NG2 6HF', 1), 
    (1, '2018-07-20', 'NG2 6HF', 2), 
    (1, '2018-07-20', 'NG2 6HF', 3), 
    (2, '2018-07-25', 'ABC DEF', 1)

WITH base AS (
SELECT 
    INCIDENT_ID
    , INCIDENT_DATE
    , INCIDENT_POSTCODE
    , ARRAY_AGG(PARTY_ID) AS PARTY_ID_ARRAY
FROM ntest  
GROUP BY 
    INCIDENT_ID
    , INCIDENT_DATE
    , INCIDENT_POSTCODE
) 
SELECT 
    INCIDENT_ID
    , INCIDENT_DATE
    , INCIDENT_POSTCODE
    , PARTY_ID_ARRAY[0] AS PARTY_ID
    , PARTY_ID_ARRAY[1] AS PARTY_ID2
    , PARTY_ID_ARRAY[2] AS PARTY_ID3
    , PARTY_ID_ARRAY[3] AS PARTY_ID4
FROM base
```

Result:

| INCIDENT_ID | INCIDENT_DATE | INCIDENT_POSTCODE | PARTY_ID | PARTY_ID2 | PARTY_ID3 | PARTY_ID4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-07-20 | NG2 6HF | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 2018-07-25 | ABC DEF | 1 |  |  |  |